# Append child element in full calendar api using eventRender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, fullcalendar

I have a simple SVG in my app, now on hover, I would like to append this div to a certain element dynamically in full calendar API

> UPDATE: Here is my full component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { Calendar as FullCalendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import calendartopbg from 'assets/images/calendar_bg.png';
import cloud from 'assets/images/calendar_chmurka.png';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Calendar = () => {
    const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState('');
    const calendarRef = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (calendarRef.current) {
             console.log(FullCalendar);
            setCalendar(new FullCalendar(calendarRef.current, {
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin],
                theme: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear',

                  },  
                  views: {
                    day: {
                      titleFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'
                    }
                  },

                  googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',
                  events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
                  eventClick: function(arg) {

                    // opens events in a popup window
                    window.open(arg.event.url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=600');

                    // prevents current tab from navigating
                    arg.jsEvent.preventDefault();
                  },
        eventRender: function(info){
                      console.log(info.el);
                      var imageData = document.getElementById('imageDataContaainer')

                    console.log(imageData)

                    info.el.appendChild(imageData);
                  },
            }));        
        }
    }, [calendarRef.current]);

    console.log(calendar);

    return (
        <>
           <CalendarBackgroundWrapper>
                <img style={imagestyle} src={calendartopbg} />
         </CalendarBackgroundWrapper>

            <CalendarContainer ref={calendarRef}>
                {calendar && calendar.render ? calendar.render(): null}
            </CalendarContainer>
        <div id="imageDataContaainer">
            <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <defs>
                    <mask id="image-mask">
                        <circle id="outer" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
                        <circle id="inner" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
                    </mask>
                </defs>
            </svg>
        </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Calendar;
```

On console I can see this div , then there is following error

```
app.js?1:121281 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at Calendar.eventRender (app.js?1:121281)
```

What is wrong with my code here?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a declarative way. Can you elaborate on the use case a little more like in which component does the svg needs to be shown?

Comment: @DennisVash how do I do that?

Comment: Please make a producible example, show us to whom you want to append, and how `eventRender` is called, better make a codesandbox

Comment: And if you already have the component, why just not conditionally render it?

Comment: @DennisVash its just a div I would like to append to a calendar event, am using full calendar API, If I use to create an element and append it it works fine, but the svg is contained a lot of other stuff that is why I don't want to use create an element, I just add it to the dom and append it on my event.

Comment: I have added my full component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you trying to do and why you need an "event render" for it, but the ["React way" is conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) a component.

Mutating the DOM (like appending child) is an anti-pattern, [as it's React's responsibility.](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
const App = () => {
  const [isRender, toggle] = useReducer(p => !p, false);

  return (
    <>
      {isRender && <SVGComponent />}
      <button onClick={toggle}>Render SVG</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit great-noether-kn5mp]

Comment: Thanks, Denis, I have updated my component check it out